# What specifically is meant by "deopts" in @babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements?

Tags: javascript, performance, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I couldn't find much on the topic in this particular context, but from what I found, it seems to refer to React-level optimizations, not Babel-level optimizations. Is this a correct interpretation or am I missing something?

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements

[image]

Comment: Whoops, apologies and thank you. I thought I'd linked too. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I think it stands for "deoptimization" and means that the element wouldn't be hoisted in such case.

From the [Babel playground](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAEgJxgXhgCgJQoHwwN4BQMMCAplAK4JgwA8AFksADYCGEEAcqwLanIAiRgJgB6bAG4CAXykECoSLEQAmFOizJchYgDdWSAA4IQhiOrwt2XXqQBcMAOSNHsoiXJUaDJHgB0AcamENJikjISQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.7.4&externalPlugins=%40babel%2Fplugin-transform-react-constant-elements%407.7.4):

```js
// Before
const Hr = () => {
  return <hr className="hr" />;
};

const Hr2 = () => {
  var props = {className: 'hr'};
  return <hr {...props} />;
};

// After
var _ref =
/*#__PURE__*/
React.createElement("hr", {
  className: "hr"
});

var Hr = function Hr() {
  return _ref;
};

var Hr2 = function Hr2() {
  var props = {
    className: 'hr'
  };
  return React.createElement("hr", props);
};
```

Comment: Not sure if "hoisting" is the right term here. I mean, I guess it is, but it also is confusing due to its usual meaning in a javascript. Maybe [immutable constant *interning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#Interning) would be more precise?